# subprocess - OSError [Errno 13] - although permissions seem ok - Python 2.7 / OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, subprocess

I am new to subprocess.

When I run:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/Applications/Calculator.app'])
```

I get the OSError.

When I check for the Calculator.app's permissions, they seem fine (drwxr-xr-x). It says 'wheel' instead of 'admin' or 'staff'.

I am getting this Error with other apps too.

On the other hand I can do:

```
subprocess.call(['open', '/Applications/Calculator.app'])
```

just fine...

What am I missing? What should I check?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between first line of code, and the second??

Comment: Am I missing something or are both command identical?

Comment: Sorry for the typo! I edited it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because MacOS X desktop applications are actually directories. The executable is buried inside.

This works:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Since this happens with other apps too, how do you find the executables?

Comment: @Diego It's almost always the same pattern: `/Applications/SomeProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/SomeProgram`. Be aware that some program names have a *space* in them, which is reflected in both the directory name and the executable name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler invocation:

```
subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a', 'Calculator'])
```

The `-a` option tells `open` that `Calculator` is an app.

Comment: Thank you for the simpler version.